# masking a double over a string

Tags: string, matlab, double, mask

This is a question in MatLab...
I have two matrices, one being a (5 x 1 double) :

```
1   
2   
3   
1   
3
```

And the second matrix being a (5 x 3 string), with spaces where no character appears :

```
a  
bc   
def   
g   
hij
```

I am trying to get an output such that a (5 x 1 string) is created and outputs the nth value from each line of matrix two, where n is the value in matrix one. I am unsure how to do this using a mask which would be able to handle much larger matrces. My target matrix would have the following :

```
a   
c   
f   
g   
j
```

Thank you very much for the help!!!

Comment: Where are the matrices? What platform/language are you using?

Comment: MatLab, sorry forgot to add this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways you can accomplish this task.  I'll give you two.

## Method #1 - Generate linear indices and access elements

Use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to generate a set of linear indices that correspond to the row and column locations you want to access in your matrix.  You'll note that the column locations are the ones changing, but the row locations are always increasing by 1 as you want to access each row.  As such, given your string matrix `A`, and your columns you want to access stored in `ind`, just do this:

```
A = ['a  '; 'bc '; 'def'; 'g  ';'hij'];
ind = [1 2 3 1 3];
out = A(sub2ind(size(A), (1:numel(ind)).', ind(:)))

out =

a
c
f
g
j
```

## Method #2 - Create a sparse matrix, convert to `logical` and access

Alternatively, you can create a sparse matrix through [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) where the non-zero entries are rows vary from 1 up to as many elements as you have in `ind` and the columns vary like what you have given us.

```
S = sparse((1:numel(ind)).',ind(:),true,size(A,1),size(A,2));
A = A.'; out = A(S.');
```

Be mindful that you are trying to access each element in a row-major fashion, yet MATLAB will do this in a column-major format.  As such, we would need to transpose our data matrix, and also take our sparse matrix and transpose that too.  The end result should give you the same order as Method #1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I tried implementing method #1 as it made a bit more sense to me, however I am getting a new error 'Out of range subscript.'  Any clue as to why this may be happening?

Comment: @TBMatLab - You said that your matrix had spaces in between each character.  When I created the matrix that way, I managed to get the right results.  Let me update my answer.

Comment: @TBMatLab - OK, take a look at how I created the matrix.  Is that the same as how you created yours?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I mean to write the original post such that there are spaces where there are not letters, such that row one would read 'a' 'space' 'space', and row two would read 'b' 'c' 'space'

Comment: @TBMatLab ahaha, that makes sense.  That's easy.  Give me 30 seconds.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That was so much easier than my attempts at using for loops!